# Does defragmenting your disk or using RAID 5 break MongoDB's indexes?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Since MongoDB's indexes are pointers to locations on the disk, does the O/S break these indexes when block data is moved on the disk for any reason? i.e. defragmenting or RAID re-balancing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of storage format on disk varies by storage engine, but as at MongoDB 3.6 the indexes reference locations within *files* on disk, not raw pointers to a block device. Block changes at the filesystem or device level do not require changes to MongoDB's internal data file structure.

However, I would be wary of running defragmentation or RAID-rebalancing utilities on a filesystem with MongoDB (or other applications) active.  Storage maintenance will have significant performance overhead. Depending on your environment (O/S, filesystem, and the utility used), defragmenting a live file system may also require file locking that could interfere with a running application.

If your goal is defragmenting to regain space or efficiency in MongoDB data files, a recommended approach would be using a replica set deployment (or sharded cluster backed by replica sets) where you can [re-sync one secondary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/) at a time. Re-syncing a secondary will rebuild the data files and indexes, and can be done as an online procedure assuming you have sufficient [fault tolerance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/#consider-fault-tolerance) with other data-bearing members in your replica set.

Also note that RAID 5 is not recommended for MongoDB production deployments. As per the [MongoDB Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#raid), RAID 10 is recommended for optimal RAID performance.